# Re-format JSON object - extract inner properties to top level

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following JSON object:

```
{
    id: "id string",
    test: {
        everything inside test
    },
    rest_id: "rest_id string"
}
```

I want to re-format the object a bit so it is as follows:

```
{
    everything inside test,
    id: "rest_id string" // pulled from rest_id
}
```

and finally need to get the rid of the original `id` property. What is the best way for me to re-format this `JSON` object?

Comment: _"finally need to get the rid of the original id property"_  can you please clarify this? Why is it in your example result if you don't want it?

Comment: id takes the value of rest_id and rest_id is deleted. Basically a swap in value between the two and then delete rest_id

Comment: It would help illustrate what you want if you used different string values for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new object with the properties you want using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const before = {
  id: "id string",
  test: {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
    baz: 'baz',
    id: 'i will be lost'
  },
  rest_id: "rest_id string"
}

const after = {
  ...before.test,
  id: before.rest_id
}

console.log(after)
```

Note that if there are any `id` properties in `test`, they will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.assign` to promote the contents of the inner object, then the delete operator to delete the inner object and the unwanted `id` key.

```js
let input = {
  id: "some string",
  test: {
    someKey: 'someValue'
  },
  rest_id: "some string"
}

input = Object.assign(input, input.test)
delete input.test
delete input.id

console.log(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first verify if `obj` and `obj.test` exist, if they do iterate through all properties in `obj.test` and write them to `obj`.

Then you can replace `obj.id` with `obj.rest_id` if it exists.

The old properties can be deleted safely.

```js
let obj = {
  id: "some string",
  test: {
    something: "hey hey hey",
    something_else: "ok",
    also_this: "alright"
  },
  rest_id: "some other string"
}

if (obj && obj.test) {
  if(Object.keys(obj.test).length) {
    Object.keys(obj.test).forEach((key, value) => {
        obj[key] = value
    });
  }
  delete obj.test
}

if (obj && obj.rest_id) {
  obj.id = obj.rest_id
  delete obj.rest_id
}

console.log(obj)
```